Session datatable getting cleared based on another datatable
I am facing a weird issue in ASP.Net MVC. I am casting a DataTable session variable into another DataTable and when I clear items from second DataTable, they are also getting cleared from Session variable.
dataTable = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
dataTable.Rows.Clear(); //after this line Session["MyDataTable"] becomes empty

Session["MyDataTable"] contains DataTable and once I clear it from dataTable, that session datatable is also getting emptied. Any idea why?

It's referencing the same object in memory, because a DataTable is a class, hence a reference type. What's the real issue, why you think you need to clear the rows? Instead use a new DataTable by using dataTable = dataTable.Clone() (empty table with same columns)

If you want to get a copy of the table in the session, you can use dataTable = ((DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"]).Copy(). This is really a new one (casting does not create a new instance)

Casting does not make a copy, so you are still dealing with a reference to the original DataTable. You would need to create a new DataTable and duplicate or clone the contents.
